# Add pop up message on big-commerce site

Tags: html, css, web, bigcommerce

I have a big commerce website and I need to add a pop up message when customers make checkout the order. For example, when customer make order and in the checkout page I need to announce that "there will be delay on delivery during xxx day". How can I achieve that? Please any help appreciated.

Comment: You need to include far more context on your project, sorry. What language is it built in? Are you using any front end framework? What have you tried so far? Does the 'xxx day' need to be a dynamic value? etc

Comment: The website built in php but in admin page you can edit the html file. Everything i add on back end will have effect on front end and Big-commerce will allow you to edit some html file. The xxx day can be anything  like Memorial day or something . I tried by adding the text  in the checkout.html code but it seems not right but it will be great like when the customer click the checkout button to display the Message"there will be delay on delivery during Memorial day ".

Comment: It sounds like you're using a ready-made eCommerce platform then? I'd suggest maybe using Google to find tutorials and/or plugins for the software that already achieve what you want to do. Or is it a custom built php template?

Comment: Its not a ready made eCommerce platform . We did a lot on the but now we need to add something on it.

Comment: Does it have to be a pop up or can it be an inline message? I assume you are using blueprint and not stencil.